# Why won't my CSS work on other pages besides the index?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates

I'm working in Adobe Dreamweaver on a simple text-and-option-buttons game right now. The index serves as the first part of the story and I've linked my external CSS file at the top, which sets text on the left of the screen and an image and option buttons on the right, while also, you know, styling things. The buttons link to forking 'path' files (path1, path2, etc) which are exactly like the index in style but vary in story text and option text. On my index page, the CSS works, but whenever I preview the different path pages, it doesn't appear. Weird thing is, I literally copied and pasted the link to the CSS file from my index page to my path1 and path2 files.

At first I thought this could have been because I used the Dreamweaver template feature on the path1 file, so I created path2 without use of the template to see if that was the problem, but that didn't fix anything. Both path1 and path2 appeared without CSS.

This is my code at the moment:

```
<title>Path 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/mpStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/kxy7nko.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="mpScripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <section class="leftsection">
            <article> 
                <div class="story-section">
                    <p>New text </p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="rightsection">
            <article>
    <!--- etc etc -->
```

(And here's `index.html` vvv)

```
<title>Midnight Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mpStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/kxy7nko.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="mpScripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <section class="leftsection">
            <article> 
                <div class="story-section">
                    <p>The place looks no more abandoned than the rest of the city. You know you're taking a risk by going another night without a roof over your head, so... </p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="rightsection">
            <article>
<!--- etc, etc -->
```

I saw a question similar to this and it was suggested to type a path like this: (link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/mpStyles.css") but that didn't work either. I just started using HTML about four months ago, so bear with me. It's probably something super obvious that I'm missing.

Comment: So the css loads for `Index.html`? Are the other html pages in a different folder?

Answer (score 1):

Change your reference to your CSS file to include a preceding forward slash:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/mpStyles.css">
```

If this does not work, this suggests that your root directory is set to something other than the folder intended.

If you update the above link to the below does this work? Obviously replacing project-name with the name of your project folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/project-name/stylesheets/mpStyles.css">
```